# Why does the following function set filetype=conf?

Tags: vim

I have the following function in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd Filetype mkd call SetWritingOptions()

function SetWritingOptions()
  colorscheme pencil
  setlocal background=light
  setlocal guifont=Cousine\ 11
  setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us
  setlocal noexpandtab
  setlocal textwidth=52
  setlocal linespace=4
  setlocal noruler
  setlocal nonumber
  setlocal wrap
  setlocal linebreak
  setlocal nolist
  setlocal display+=lastline
  execute "Goyo"
endfunction
```

(Goyo is a distration-free mode plugin for Vim: https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim)

I added this for the purpose of working with `markdown` files

Now everything works OK except I end up with `filetype=conf`, which doesn't happend if I remove `execute "Goyo"`

Why is this? How can I modify the function so I end up with `filetype=mkd` instead?

(I tried adding `filetype=mkd` at the end, but Vim just keeps calling the function until it breaks).

Comment: Why do you have the line `execute "Goyo"` instead of just `Goyo`?  What do you get from `:verbose set ft?`, `:Goyo`, `:verbose set ft?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goyo command opens the current document in a new window in a new tab surrounded by 4 invisible padding windows. Window-local settings (`setlocal`) will not be applied to this new Goyo window.

So the right way to achieve this is to use [`g:goyo_callbacks`](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim#callbacks), with which you can specify two functions that are called when a new Goyo window is created and when it's closed.

Please notice that the most of the settings in your example are global that cannot be applied locally, so you might want to revert those settings in the second callback function.

```
function! SetWritingOptions()
  colorscheme pencil
  setlocal background=light
  setlocal guifont=Cousine\ 11
  setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us
  setlocal noexpandtab
  setlocal textwidth=52
  setlocal linespace=4
  setlocal noruler
  setlocal nonumber
  setlocal wrap
  setlocal linebreak
  setlocal nolist
  setlocal display+=lastline
endfunction

function! UnsetWritingOptions()
  " Fill in!
  " Revert global options
endfunction

let g:goyo_callbacks = [function('SetWritingOptions'), function('UnsetWritingOptions')]

augroup GoyoMarkdown
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType mkd nested if !has('vim_starting')|execute 'Goyo'|endif
  autocmd VimEnter *.md,*.mkd,*.markdown nested Goyo
augroup END
```